# Get all the cells of a section UIcollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

Dear iOs developpers,

I'm trying to get all the cells of a given section in a Collection View.
Something like:

```
NSInteger section = [self getSectionForIndexPath:indexPath];
NSArray *cells = [self.collectionView cellsForItemAtSection:section];
```

My collectionView looks like this :

[image]

And I would like to prevent a new inserted cell to be "over" the next or previous one. But this is actually a bad idea to rely on the view to make my verifications

**Edit**

We can not access hidden cells. So the only method reachable is cellForItemAtIndexPath.

To conclude if I want to access information about my cells, I need to get the data source of section.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? Why do you need to get all of the cells?

Comment: This is not really possible as cells are reused, so a section with more items than are visible on one screen will have repeated cells. The only method you have for accessing cells is cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: I have a collection view holding events. And when  I add a new event I want to make sure that this new event is not over another one. One section is one day

Comment: So I guess I must find another way to reach the informations in cells

Comment: what do mean by  ....not over another one...can you elaborate

Comment: You should have a data model that holds your data, which dictates, through your view controller, to your collection view what is to be displayed. It is not good to rely on your views for data.